# Why additional gems has been installed when I wanted just one called "jekyll"?

Tags: ruby, console, rubygems

I'm passing through some course at codecademy and I wonder why this command additional installed other gems (or what is it?). Win10 OS.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X690c.png)

Comment: Jekyll probably requires them to work. When a library is installed, all of its dependencies are typically installed along with it if they aren't already on your system.

Comment: So that's normal behaviour, right? Then can I find exact list of dependencies somewhere in some doc? Or I dig into it too deep? Just wonder how it works

Comment: And how exactly all that other stuff except jekyll are called? Gems as well or dependencies? Or both termins are correct?

Comment: If those are the dependencies of Jekyll, yes, this is the expected behavior. If you wanted to make sure though, you could find the Jekyll website/Github page. It will usually list all the dependencies. Note though, you may have to dig pretty deep if you want to look into all of the libraries listed in the image. Some of those may be dependencies of dependencies. Let's say Jekyll requires library B. B will be installed when you install Jekyll. But say B requires library C. C will also be installed when you install Jekyll. There's a reason we use programs to manage dependencies nowadays.

Comment: And I actually don't know Ruby. I'm under the assumption that "Gem" is just the word Ruby uses for "library".

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. I wish I could rate your answers, but I haven't this feature yet.

Comment: Well, I haven't posted an answer, these are just comments. I'm not sure enough in my response to post an answer as, like I said, I don't know Ruby, and have never used Jekyll. In every language I've ever used though, the behavior I described above has been pretty consistent. If Jekyll is the first library you've ever installed, you'll probably notice that when you install more libraries later, it will install less since a lot of the libraries are probably already installed. I've gone to install libraries before and found that I already have them because some other library already needed it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: RubyGems is Ruby's package management system. I'm not sure what ecosystems you are familiar with; a gem is equivalent to an egg in Python, a Maven package in Java, a crate in Rust, an npm package in Node.js, and a NuGet package in .NET.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ahh, thanks. I'm kind of familiar with Maven since that's what Clojure's Leiningen uses internally afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the ruby gems web page for jkyll at 
https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll 
you will see that it has run-time dependencies listed for 10 other gems.

When you attempt to install jekyll, those other gems will be installed if they are not already installed.

This automatic dependency management is seen as a major plus for Ruby's gem system.